# Python error on class method: 'takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'

Tags: python

I have a python script which runs through different functions to grid up a raster and push up to an s3 bucket etc.

The script works fine until this line:

```
print(str(datetime.now()) + ' createSimpleExtent (start)')
self.createSimpleExtent(self)
print(str(datetime.now()) + ' createSimpleExtent (end)')
```

The `createSimpleExtent` function is set out as below:

```
    def createSimpleExtent(self):
        try:
            self.simple_ddb_update(self.jobDict['jobid'], 'running', 'Creating simplified polygon in progress')
            self.CreateMask(self.reprojected_tif, self.mask_tif)
            self.GdalPolygonize(self.mask_tif, self.mask_tif, self.json_out, 1, self.basename)
            self.outerPolygons = self.getOuterPolygons(self.json_out)
            self.SimplifyPolygons(self.outerPolygons, float(self.jobDict['epsilon']))
            self.pp.pprint(self.json_simple_extent)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logException(e)
            raise
```

The error I then get is `TypeError: createSimpleExtent() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

I'm completely baffled by this and wondering am I missing something obvious? Where are the 2 positional arguments given? As far as I'm aware I'm only passing `self` ??

Comment: Try without passing `self`; it’s implicit, and therefore seeing `self` twice; hence ‘2  were given’.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error is being thrown, is that `self` can be thought of as an implicit argument. So passing `self` into the method is creating *two* arguments; (i.e. `self` *twice*.)

**The fix:**

Remove `self` from the function call, as:

```
self.createSimpleExtent()
```